# Scaling Problem - API Gateway and Lambda Payload limits

Tags: aws-lambda, graphql, aws-api-gateway

Our GraphQL service is going to get large requests now > 20MB. Currently getting <6MB requests. Our architecture is : 1. Client --> AWS API Gateway --> AWS Lambda. API Gateway has 10 MB payload limit, and Lambda has 6MB payload limit.

We are open to make changes in getting requests, changes in architecture as well. What solution we have for such problem ?

*[Edit] Exploring solutions other than S3 to make sure to evaluate all possible approaches to solve this problem. S3 is definitely one of the solution but exploring is there better solution available ? Example - 1>> Avoiding API Gateway and change the architecture itself 2>> Compression solutions 3>> Any streaming solutions etc.*

Comment: Split the request into smaller parts, send it to S3 and have your app ingest it from there, or use a different backend. My understanding is the 6MB/10MB limits are not adjustable.

Comment: If you're uploading files best send them straight to S3 rather than through a lambda.

Comment: You will also need to take care about Timeout of API Gateway which is fixed 30 seconds. I think you better rearchitecture to handle your scaling problem.